# Profile:Edit New Member Password Saving Issue

Tags: members, cartthrob, password

When using Profile:Edit and CartThrob together we are saving member data as part of checkout.

If we look directly at the DB the password is being saved but there is nothing in the salt column of the `exp_members` table. If you try to login on the website EE throws a `The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid` error.

If you then go to member management of the CP and enter the password just like it was during checkout, a value is added to the salt column of the DB and you can login on the website without issue.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to get Profile:Edit/CT to salt the password?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the password salted for login to work. ExpressionEngine's member login code is designed to automatically add a salt and improve the hash up login. It's pretty common for a newly-created member to not have a salt.

Obviously this doesn't answer your question completely, but maybe it'll help you narrow down the causes of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Strange that EE throws an error on the website until we 'update' the password in the CP - even though we are using the exact same password when we 'update' it.